# ORACLE SQL DDL for saving counter range criteria into table

Tags: sql, oracle, formula, ddl, performancecounter

I am working on a counter(KPI) system .The system calculates many indicators of different business logic but which are all numeric values.
For each counter range criteria a score is assigned .
For example for the counter N1 if the value = 0 so the score is 25
or the value is =-1 so the score is 0
or if the is greater than 365 so the score is 19
or if the value is between 30 and 365 so the score is 8
etc...

The actual score is calculated in a hard coded way like below :

```
CASE WHEN INDICATORS.INDICATOR_NO = 'N1' THEN 

(CASE 
when INDICATORS.INDICATOR_VALUE =0 then 25
when INDICATORS.INDICATOR_VALUE =-1 then 0
  when INDICATORS.INDICATOR_VALUE>=365 then 19
  when INDICATORS.INDICATOR_VALUE>=30 and INDICATORS.INDICATOR_VALUE<=365 then 8
  when INDICATORS.INDICATOR_VALUE <=29 then 0




  else -100
  END )

WHEN INDICATORS.INDICATOR_NO = 'N2' THEN   
(CASE 
when INDICATORS.INDICATOR_VALUE=-1  then 0
  when INDICATORS.INDICATOR_VALUE >=1 then 16
  when INDICATORS.INDICATOR_VALUE<1  then 0

   else -100
END) 


WHEN INDICATORS.INDICATOR_NO = 'N3' THEN   
(CASE 
    when INDICATORS.INDICATOR_VALUE =-1 then 0
  when INDICATORS.INDICATOR_VALUE >=1 then 13
  when INDICATORS.INDICATOR_VALUE<1  then 0


   else -100
END) 


WHEN INDICATORS.INDICATOR_NO = 'N4' THEN   
(CASE 
    when INDICATORS.INDICATOR_VALUE =-1 then 0
  when INDICATORS.INDICATOR_VALUE <=1095 then 0
   when INDICATORS.INDICATOR_VALUE >1095 and INDICATORS.INDICATOR_VALUE<=3650  then 3 
   when INDICATORS.INDICATOR_VALUE >3650 then 12
   else -100
END)
```

My idea is to create a table named L_COUNTER that will hold the counter name and unit then create a second table L_COUNTER_RANGE thah will hold a min value and max value so i can calculate the score all the counter using a loop on MYSQL and it will be more easy and dynamic if any future counter has to be created .

Could you please suggest the DDL of the table L_COUNTER_RANGE to hold the criteria range dynamically .

I have already tried the following DDL but 
it isn't a good idea since if a range has only a >= condition then it will meet two ranges criteria instead of only 1.
`L_COUNTER_RANGE (COUNTER_ID, RANGE_ID, MIN_VALUE, MAX_VALUE, SCORE)`

Answer (score 2):

You seem to pretty much have described it:

```
create table counter_range (
    indicator_no varchar2(255) references indicators (indicator_no),
    min_value number,
    max_value number,
    factor number
);
```

I am not sure if the `else` is really important.  I think the indictors should never be `null`, but you can use a double `null` to match null values.

So:

```
insert into counter_range 
    select 'N2', -1, -1, 0 from dual union all
    select 'N2', 1, null, 16 from dual union all
    select 'N2', null, -1, 0 from dual union all
    select 'N2', null, null, -100 from dual;
```

Then the `join` is a little complicated, but:

```
from indicators i join
     counter_range cr
     on ( (i.indicator_value >= cr.min_value or
          (cr.min_value is null and cr.max_value is not null)
         ) and
         (i.indicator_value <= cr.max_value or
          (cr.max_value is null and cr.min_value is not null)
         ) 
       ) or
       (i.indicator_value is null and cr.min_value is null and cr.max_value is null)
```

Eliminating the `NULL` condition would simplify the logic.

```
from indicators i join
     counter_range cr
     on (i.indicator_value >= cr.min_value or
         cr.min_value is null 
        ) and
        (i.indicator_value <= cr.max_value or
         cr.max_value is null
        )
```

Comment: Thank you so much Gordon, the solution fits perfectly the need.